# Maintaining whitespaces and line breaks with xsl transformation from xml to html

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am trying to write an xslt in order to transform an XML to an HTML. At a certain point, I have an XML element that can contain text inserted by the user. It is important to preserve any extra whitespace and line breaks (adding extra line breaks in order to not overflow the containing div it is fine).

The XML looks like this (I add the image to clearly specify how it is formatted):
[image: original xml to transform]

I have tried to use

`white-space: pre-wrap;`

but in the final HTML I get that every time that there is a line break in the XML, some extra white spaces are added in the beginning of the line. The XSL script looks like this:

```
 <xsl:when test="hl7v3:title='event.description'">
     <div>
        <p style="white-space: pre-wrap; text-align:left;"><xsl:copy-of select="./hl7v3:text/hl7v3:paragraph/text()" /></p>
     </div>
 </xsl:when>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: result in html]

Any suggestion on how to fix thinks?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use the HTML serialization method in the XSLT processor, then it might adjust its behaviour to take account of HTML elements such as `pre`, but it's not going to take any note of CSS directives. I think you probably have to switch indentation off (`xsl:output indent="no"`). If you're using an up-to-date XSLT processor then you can switch indentation off for specific elements using the `suppress-indentation` option on `xsl:output`: but even that only takes account of the HTML element name, not of CSS styles.